Dialog Window open second Monitor instead of Application Monitor
I want to open dialog Window Top of main application UI and disable and blurred the back UI (Application window). To do that i showed a black and blurred window on top of application window and then Shown dialog popup on top of black blurred window. But issue is Application Window shows PC's Monitor-1 and black blurred window & Popup UI shows PC's monitor-2 instead of monitor-1.
My code:
public void ShowModalWindow(Window window)
    {
        if (window != null) //Here window is Popup UI
        {
            Window modalWindow = new Window //This is for black blurred Window
            {
                Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
                Top = Application.Current.MainWindow.Top,
                Left = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left,
                Width = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width,
                Height = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height,
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner,
                WindowState = Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState,
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
                ShowInTaskbar = false,
                AllowsTransparency = true,
                Background = Brushes.Black,
                Opacity = 0.7
            };

            // Show modal window
            modalWindow.Owner.Effect = new BlurEffect { Radius = 5, KernelType = KernelType.Gaussian };
            modalWindow.Show();

            // Open the dialog and wait for it to close
            window.Owner = modalWindow;
            window.ShowDialog();

            //close the modal window
            modalWindow.Owner.Effect = null;
            modalWindow.Close();

            //Main Window lost focus during popup closing. It fixes the issue
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus();
        }
    }


Why don't you set Application.Current.MainWindow to the dialog window's Owner?

@emoacht, because this is my application main UI.
I've set this from my Main UI.-> Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
